# Getting error TypeError: next is not a function

Tags: node.js

I'm getting error "**TypeError: next is not a function**" while trying to authenticate dashboard route in nodejs.
I am trying to make and CRUD app with node and mongoDB suing these modules **express ejs mongoose bcryptjs passport passport-local**.
Getting this error when I submit login form.
I am new in nodejs, Please help me

Thanks in advance.

**auth/protect.js file**

```
const protectRoute = (req, res, next) =>{
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next();
    }
    console.log('Please log in to continue');
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
   const allowIf = (req, res, next) =>{
     if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
       return next();
     }
    res.redirect('/dashboard');      
   }
  
  module.exports = {
      protectRoute,
       allowIf,
    };
```

**routes/login.js file**

```
const express = require("express");

const {
  registerView,
  loginView,
  registerUser,
  loginUser,
} = require("../controllers/loginController");
const { dashboardView } = require("../controllers/dashboardController");
const { protectRoute } = require("../auth/protect");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/register", registerView);
router.get("/login", loginView);
router.get("/", loginView);

//Dashboard
router.get("/dashboard", protectRoute, dashboardView);

router.post("/register", registerUser);
router.post("/login", loginUser);

module.exports = router;
```

**server.js file**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require("passport");
const { loginCheck } = require("./auth/passport");

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

const db = require("./models");
db.mongoose
  .connect(db.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to the database!");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Cannot connect to the database!", err);
    process.exit();
  });

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(session({
  secret:'oneboy',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// simple route
app.use('/', require('./routes/login'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Comment: How do you set up/call your route in your `app.js`?

Comment: @eol I have calling **login** route file in server.js, ``app.use('/', require('./routes/login'));`` and in login route file I have called ``const { protectRoute } = require("../auth/protect");`` and used it ``router.get("/dashboard", protectRoute, dashboardView);``

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there, it's hard to read in a comment ...

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ArnavThorat, Thank you, I will do it next time, it was my first time to ask question.

Comment: That's fine. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have missed to call a function `loginCheck(passport);` in my **server.js** file that's why I was getting error during login form submission.

**server.js** starting code

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require("passport");
//var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const { loginCheck } = require("./auth/passport");
loginCheck(passport);
........................................
```

I was added this function in **auth/passport.js** file
**passport.js**

```
//js
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
//Load model
const User = require("../models/User");
const loginCheck = passport => {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, (email, password, done) => {
      //Check customer
      User.findOne({ email: email })
        .then((user) => {
          if (!user) {
            console.log("wrong email");
            return done();
          }
          //Match Password
          bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error, isMatch) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            if (isMatch) {
              return done(null, user);
            } else {
              console.log("Wrong password");
              return done();
            }
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    })
  );
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (error, user) => {
      done(error, user);
    });
  });
};
module.exports = {
  loginCheck,
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to use next() in normal function then it will give an error

```js
const allowIf = (req, res, next) =>{
    return next(); // throw an error - TypeError: next is not a function
}
allowIf();
```

So use next() as a Callback argument to the middleware function. It will work fine in this case. Try this:

```
const protectRoute = (req, res, next) =>{
    console.log('protectRoute');
    return next();
}
app.get('/', protectRoute);
```

Comment: its not working. I have tried as per your instructions but getting same error. ``const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const protectRoute = (req, res, next) =>{
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log('protectRoute');
      return next();
    }
    console.log('Please log in to continue');
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
  app.get('/', protectRoute);``

Comment: It's working fine for me. not giving error

const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const protectRoute = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log('protectRoute');
        return next();
    }
    console.log('Please log in to continue');
    res.redirect('/login');
}

app.get('/', protectRoute);